# Python - Parse gmail messages().get() with format='raw'

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

I'm using gmail api to get messages from my mailbox.
But when using format='raw' in get method, I can't parse the returned data in 'raw' filed.

```
service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id, format='raw').execute()
```

This is in the document,

> "raw": Returns the full email message data with body content in the raw field as a base64url encoded string; the payload field is not used.

and I tried

- base64.urlsafe_b64decode(raw.encode('utf-8'))
- base64.urlsafe_b64decode(raw.encode('ascii'))
- base64.urlsafe_b64decode(raw.encode('cp932'))   the message is in Japanese
- base64.urlsafe_b64decode(raw)

<del>None of the returned value is readable.</del>

I got all ASCII words and numbers, but none of the Japanese words are readable:

- Delivered-To
- Received
- X-Received
- ...
- Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
- Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

And when it comes to Japanese (or message body?), the message turns to something like: '''6Ie855Sw5qeYDQoNCuOBhOOBpOOCguOBiuS4luipseOBq+OBquOBo+OBpuOBiuOCiuOBvuOBmeOA
gg0K44Oq44Ol44Km44Gn44GZ ...... PjwvZGl2PjwvZGl2PjwvZGl2PjwvZGl2PjwvZGl2PjwvZGl2Pg0KPC9kaXY+
PC9kaXY+PC9kaXY+DQo='''

Please help me out!!

Comment: Is it necessary to use the raw format, as opposed to their JSON payload?

Comment: this is not gmail API's problem. It returned a raw format in base64url  as promised, how you decode is another story.

Comment: Have you tried `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(raw.encode('UTF8'))`?